# Magento 2.1 and symlinks

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, template, deploy, file

My server structure is as follows:

> /var/www/htdocs_webroot/shop -> symlink to:
>   /var/www/shop/deploy_xxxx-xx-xx/htdocs

So I can redeploy magento easily and switch back and forth with one simple command.
My problem is: Magento doesn't play along.

I redeployed to a more current version and changed the symlink. Then I redeployed static files, reindexed and flushed the cache.
Yet activating template hints shows that templates are loaded from the older folder instead.
Whereas the real problem is that Magento wants to load the templates with the physical file path instead of the virtual one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question, but have you cleared cache?

Comment: Yeah maybe I should have said that I: flushed the cache, reindexed and redeployed static files.

Comment: My current guess is that either I setup Magento in the wrong way somehow so it took the physical path or Magento always resolves to the physical path. I hope it's not the second one :(